# Difference between httpd vs httpd start

Tags: vps, lamp

My top -c was showing `/usr/sbin/httpd -k start` and now showing `/usr/sbin/httpd`.

Whats the difference?

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/sbin/httpd -k start` is the first Apache process that runs, to start the service. It listens for new connections, say on ports 80 and 443.

Each time a new connection is received, the first process forks a new one, `/usr/sbin/httpd`, to handle the new request. So there's one httpd process for each request, plus the original one.